# Meteor - What is the purpose of "ROOT_URL" and to what should it be defined?

Tags: nginx, meteor

I'm getting some problems to make spiderable work with PhantomJS on my Ubuntu server. I saw this troubleshooting on [Meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable):

> Ensure that the ROOT_URL that your Meteor server is configured to use
>   is accessible from the server itself. (Since v0.8.1.3[1])

I think that this could be a possible answer to why it is not working. What is exactly the purpose of this environment variable?

My application is publicly accessible on `http://gentlenode.com/` but my `proxy_pass` on nginx is set to `http://gentlenode/`.

```
# HTTPS Server
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name gentlenode.com;
    # ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://gentlenode/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # ...
    }
}
```

Should I set `ROOT_URL` to `http://gentlenode.com/`, to `http://gentlenode/` or to `http://localhost/`?

You can find my nginx configuration here: https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/9877434

Comment: Is the meteor instance on the same server as nginx? In other words, are you proxying to a localhost?

Comment: Yes, the meteor instance is running on the same server. I think I am proxying to a localhost, here is my nginx file to be sure: https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/9877434#file-meteor-ssl-nginx

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `ROOT_URL` environment variable should be set to the URL that clients will be accessing your application with. So in your case, it would be `http://gentlenode.com` or `https://gentlenode.com`.

The `ROOT_URL` environment variable is read by [`Meteor.absoluteUrl`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl), which is used in many (core) packages. Thus, setting `ROOT_URL` may be a requirement if you use these packages. [`spiderable`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/1a4956e89aa5192f18bf32353f78a735d35c1890/packages/spiderable/spiderable_server.js#L62) is one such package.

```js
// Line 62 of spiderable_server.js
var url = Spiderable._urlForPhantom(Meteor.absoluteUrl(), req.url);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll admit that we don't use spiderable so I'm not 100% certain if this will fix your problem, but here's what we do...

We set ROOT_URL to the URL which clients will use to initially connect. In your case, the nginx config automatically upgrades all HTTP requests to HTTPS, so all requests will be seen by your app under `https://gentlenode.com`. I think you should start your server after:

```
export ROOT_URL=https://gentlenode.com
```

Your `proxy_pass` section may be correct. We manually spell out the name of the local port. So we'd write:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:58080;
```

If you have something that works already, this may not be necessary. I don't know all the quirks of nginx well enough to say if that part matters.