# How to change the domain in meteor email template?

Tags: email, meteor

I want to change the domain name from "localhost" to "www.someotherdomain.com" in the email template which send from Meteor verify/reset/signup process. It should be simply a global variable settings but I couldn't find it. Any tips would be much appreciated.

To change:

http://localhost:3000/reset-password/abcdefghijklmnoprqstuvwxyz

to:

http://www.someotherdomain.com/reset-password/abcdefghijklmnoprqstuvwxyz

Thanks,

UPDATE: found answer in the below link.

[Meteor - What is the purpose of "ROOT_URL" and to what should it be defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046186/meteor-what-is-the-purpose-of-root-url-and-to-what-should-it-be-defined)

Answer (score 0):

You can set this with [Meteor.absoluteUrl()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl). Ex:

```
Meteor.absoluteUrl("http://www.someotherdomain.com");
```

OR, set it with the environment variable `ROOT_URL`